# How to get seller sent of messages from ebay GetMyMessages API?

Tags: api

I found that all the data I got using the GetMyMessages API was messages sent by buyers to sellers. I wanted to get messages sent by sellers to buyers .

```
                    ApiContext Context = userModel.GetApiContext();
                    DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-14);
                    DateTime endDate = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(1);
                    Console.WriteLine("StartDate:" + startDate + "--------------------EndDate:" + endDate);

                    GetMyMessagesCall getMyMessageApiCall = new GetMyMessagesCall(Context);
                    getMyMessageApiCall.StartTime = startDate;
                    getMyMessageApiCall.EndTime = endDate;

                    DetailLevelCodeType[] detailLevels = new DetailLevelCodeType[] { DetailLevelCodeType.ReturnHeaders };
                    getMyMessageApiCall.DetailLevelList = new DetailLevelCodeTypeCollection(detailLevels); 
                    getMyMessageApiCall.GetMyMessages();
                    MyMessagesMessageTypeCollection messages = getMyMessageApiCall.MessageList;
```

Comment: You need to share the code where you are exactly fetching the messages. Say *GetMyMessages API*

Comment: That's the code I posted. It uses eBay SDK for. NET. SDK version 1065.